# Where can I learn to define mathematical terms?

Tags: soft-question, terminology

For example, take the following:

> The radian measure of a central angle of a circle is defined as the
>   ratio of the length of the arc the angle subtends, *s*, divided by the
>   radius of the circle, *r*.

This is one of the many definitions of a *radian*.

Firstly, what is this kind of definition, where temporary, conventionally-named variables are introduced such as the "*r*" in "radius of the circle, *r*", known as?

And is the skill of writing such definitions developed intrinsically? Or are there formal guidelines, a 'nomenclature' of some sort, where the defining-process is formally described?

Comment: The mention of radius here is hardly "arbitrary". And of course, one doesn't really need to name the variables in order for this definition to make sense.

Comment: It's mostly experience. There was a long time where mathematicians didn't use temporary in-definition variables, or variables at all, and it took a lot longer to write various theorems and definitions.

Comment: @Travis: I too felt that "arbitrary" was the wrong word to use. Could you perhaps suggest an edit?

Comment: I'm not sure precisely what you mean to convey here, but maybe "auxiliary" is roughly the right idea? But whether one literally names the variables in the definition is a matter of convenience---one can write logically equivalent definitions without referring to them (and as Thomas points out, this can be a lot wordier, and harder to parse too).

Comment: @Travis: I've updated my question. Is it better now?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I am quite aware of that. I just want to know whether this convention has a name, and whether I can formally learn it. I quite like this style of definition, as it offers clarity and convenience.

Comment: Essentially, you need to recognize what you are trying to communicate, and what your reader possibly doesn't know, and then you need to learn how to be a clear writer. All of these pieces require experience.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I had feared as much. Would you mind submitting this as answer?

Comment: Normally I only see variables like $r$ and $s$ named in a definition when they are to be used in a subsequent formula, definition, theorem, or example. This makes me think the example definition is taken from a larger work like a paper or textbook and that context makes the use of those variables sensible.

Comment: @ToddWilcox: I agree. I have mostly encountered such definitions in textbooks, usually those about geometry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to recognize what you are trying to communicate, and what your reader possibly doesn't know, and then you need to learn how to be a clear writer. All of these pieces require experience.

There is a formalism in making sure that you have given a definition that is accurate to what you want, but this is more a question of how to write clearly and convey information.

Indeed, in heavily formalized mathematics, we simply "skip" definitions - the languages of first- and second-order mathematics does not contain a provision for adding definitions, and everything can be done without definitions. Definitions themselves are just shorthand for our convenience. They are a means of human communication.

The above definition is an interesting example, because it requires a separate step to get the result we all "know," that the radians measurement is independent of the radius of the circle. You can't actually write the definition without that problem. No matter what definition you use, you will need to prove something. That's because the independence of the radius choice is a feature of Euclidean geometry, not inherent in the definition alone.